# Channel Divinity: Control Undead question

Tags: dnd-5e, paladin

I had a question about the Oathbreaker Paladin's Channel Divinity option, Control Undead.

> **Control Undead**: As an action, you target one undead creature you can see within 30 feet of you. The target must make a Wisdom saving throw.  On a failed save, the target must obey your commands for the next 24 hours, or until you use this Channel Divinity option again. An undead whose challenge rating is equal to or greater than your paladin level is immune to this effect. *(Chapter 5, Pg 97, Dungeon Masters Guide)*

Does this mean, for example, that if I had a lvl 6 paladin I could control an undead creature with a CR of 5 or less for 24 hours?

Answer (score 7):

## Yes, a level 6 Oathbreaker Paladin could control an undead creature with a CR of 5 or less for 24 hours.

The description is vague for how that control is actually managed during combat.  The 3rd level [Animate Dead](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-dead) spell provides more structure for how commands are given during combat, to an undead creature.

> ...On each of your turns, you can use a bonus action to mentally command any creature you made with this spell if the creature is within 60 feet of you (if you control multiple creatures, you can command any or all of them at the same time, issuing the same command to each one). You decide what action the creature will take and where it will move during its next turn, or you can issue a general command, such as to guard a particular chamber or corridor. If you issue no commands, the creature only defends itself against hostile creatures. Once given an order, the creature continues to follow it until its task is complete....

Since this spell would be available to Wizards and Clerics at level 6, it's probably a reasonable structure for the Oathbreaker Paladin's Channel Divinity too.